# How to calculate LAI for Landsat image collection with SAVI?

Tags: google-earth-engine, savi, lai

I am a beginner in GEE. I am trying to create a model for SEBAL in GEE. I am stuck in a problem with LAI using SAVI. There is a problem with laio :(intermediate value).subtract is not a function

```
*function addLAI(image) {
    var laio = ee.Number(0.69.subtract(image.select('SAVI'))).log();
    var lai1 = laio.divide(0.59);
    var lai2 = lai2.divide(0.91).rename('LAI');
    return image.addBands(lai2)
}
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the error messages "... is not a function" are caused by the use of a method that does not exist for a particular type of `ee.Object` or when the type of certain object is not clear for GEE and thus, needs a casting. In this case,  the number needed a casting as `ee.Number(0.69)`; however, since you want to generate an image with the subtraction of 0.69 and the SAVI value, you should instead use `ee.Image.constant`. Additionally, when defining `lai2` you were calling a `lai2` object that had not been defined; therefore, I assumed it should be `lai1` instead of `lai2`. Here is the code that should perform the desired calculation.

```
function addLAI(image) {
    var laio = ee.Image.constant(0.69).subtract(image.select('SAVI')).log();
    var lai1 = laio.divide(0.59);
    var lai2 = lai1.divide(0.91).rename('LAI');
    return image.addBands(lai2);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, sir. I used your code, however, the result of LAI is homogeneous( my study area is UAE). Is it ok?

Comment: The result should not be homogeneous, unless there is no spatial variation of SAVI. I recommend first checking if SAVI is spatially homogeneous, and start debugging the script from there.